# how to make the dropdownlist in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportFavorite" runat="server" Height="16px"
    Width="190px">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I need to have the `dropdownlist` to be editable, that is when a user wants to type, it allows to type. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Is there any method using `javascript` or any other alternative without going for Ajax Control Toolkit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the ajax control toolkit, in particular...

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

and a decent tutorial here

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/combobox/how-do-i-use-the-combobox-control-cs

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bootstrap select picker and add extra attributes to your `asp:dropdownlist` such as the following:

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditStatusCode"
                  runat="server"
                  CssClass="form-control selectpicker"
                  data-live-search="true"
                  data-size="10">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You also need to add `bootstrap-select.css` and `bootstrap-select.js` to your web page.

The result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin

[jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin Demo](http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I need to save when user types. The link shows the searchable.